# Can't import custom Toolbox in ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, python-script-tool, syntaxerror

I have a custom made Toolbox and I can't make it run.

The Toolbox is called `toolbox_k` and the tool is called `sn`

I did this:

```
arcpy.ImportToolbox(r"C:\Users\user\Desktop\VST\Toolbox_k.tbx", "sn")
```

I use the `sn` with the parameters as using the GUI version and it doesn't work. It gives a syntax error:

```
sn('pathone','pathtwo')
```

**UPDATE**

Running:

```
>>> arcpy.ImportToolbox("Toolbox_PS.tbx", "tbxk")
```

gives:

```
Runtime error 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.6\arcpy\arcpy\__init__.py", line 125, in ImportToolbox
    return import_toolbox(input_file, module_name)
  File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.6\arcpy\arcpy\toolbox_code.py", line 457, in import_toolbox
    mymodule = generate_toolbox_module(toolbox, None, False, False, False, module_name, use_alt_alias)
  File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.6\arcpy\arcpy\toolbox_code.py", line 432, in generate_toolbox_module
    'exec')
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\VST\Toolbox_k.tbx", line 19
    def 00CalculateKAEK(PST=None):
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: The documentation states the expected naming, which is in the arcpy namespace: `arcpy.toolbox_tool`

Comment: So what should be changed?

Comment: When you post saying you have an error, please include the actual error text.

Comment: It was actually as you read it. Simply `Syntax error`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation:

> ```
> ImportToolbox (input_file, {module_name})
> ```
>
> - input_file - The geoprocessing toolbox to be accessed from Python.
> - module_name (optional) - If the toolbox does not have an alias, the module_name is required.
>
> When a tool is accessed through the ArcPy site package, the toolbox
>   alias where the tool is contained is a required suffix
>   (arcpy._ or arcpy..). Since ArcPy
>   depends on toolbox aliases to access and execute the correct tool,
>   aliases are extremely important when importing custom toolboxes. A
>   good practice is to always define a custom toolbox's alias; however,
>   if the toolbox alias is not defined, a temporary alias can be set as
>   the second parameter.

So try:

```
# *If* you have set an alias in your .tbx properties, 
# assuming you set the alias as "tbxk"
arcpy.ImportToolbox(r"C:\Users\user\Desktop\VST\Toolbox_k.tbx")

# If you haven't set an alias, use a temporary alias "tbxk"
arcpy.ImportToolbox(r"C:\Users\user\Desktop\VST\Toolbox_k.tbx", "tbxk")

# then
arcpy.sn_tbxk(etc...)
# or
arcpy.tbxk.sn(etc...)
```

Re. your update with the`SyntaxError` - python names can contain numbers, but must start with a letter or an underscore so you'll have to rename `def 00CalculateKAEK(PST=None)`

Comment: And then use the parameters in the last part as working with a function?

Comment: Generally yes. Assuming you have specified those parameters in your tool properties.

Comment: When importing the toolbox  as you suggested with an alias it still gives a runtime error. See updated question with the error

Comment: Your function name `def 00etc...`. Functions, variables and other names can not start with a number, they must start with a letter (or an underscore which indicates a non public name by convention).